# jq keys as concenated string

Tags: bash, jq

I have a source file that looks like

```
{
    "admin-user" : {
        "index.md": "Index",
        "user_profil.md": "User Profil"
    }
}
```

By help of bash and jq I like to concat a string of the second level keys `index.md` and `user_profile.md`. Further I like replace `.md` with `.html` (key admin-user is unknown an can change)

This is where I hang:

```
KEYS=$(cat test.json | jq  -r '.[]|keys')

concat_string=""
for i in $KEYS
    do 
        md_name=${i/.md/.html}
        concat_string="$concat_string$md_name"
    done

echo $concat_string
```

Result:

```
["index.html","user_profil.html"]
```

So the result is an array. How can I concat a string with blanks between strings?

Comment: Mind, you shouldn't be looping over strings at all; to properly loop over items you should be forming a bash array. `readarray -t keys < <(jq -r '.[] | keys[]')` and then `for i in "${keys[@]}"; do ...` -- though there are better approaches if your filenames can possibly contain newlines.

Comment: See [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) re: the `for item in $(anything)` malpractice. Very closely related is [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: (Re: why storing a list of filenames in a space-separated string is a bad idea, remember that filenames can contain spaces; if someone runs `d='uploads/ /etc/passwd '; mkdir -p "$d" && touch "$d/hello.html"`, you don't want code that iterates over HTML files in `uploads` operating on `/etc/passwd`)

Comment: (mind, filenames can _also_ contain newlines, so newline-separated strings used to store a list of filenames are a bad idea too; hence GNU tools supporting NUL-separated streams, though you can't store those in a bash string and need to use an array to represent them in a bash variable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of it can be done from within jq:

```bash
map(keys_unsorted[] | sub("\\.md$"; ".html"))
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/VqX6Pb8oXtg)

Alternatively, you can use `to_entries` to access each `.key`:

```bash
map(to_entries[].key | sub("\\.md$"; ".html"))
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/hoGTXAo6xav)

Both will give you an array of strings

```json
["index.html","user_profil.html"]
```

which you can then -still in jq- concatenate using `join` and a glue character:

```bash
jq -r 'map(keys_unsorted[] | sub("\\.md$"; ".html")) | join(" ")' test.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/F7fCwL9bxmA)

or using the alternative approach:

```bash
jq -r 'map(to_entries[].key | sub("\\.md$"; ".html")) | join(" ")' test.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/9YBhvLqgqMK)

Note: Using `keys` instead of `keys_unsorted` (as you did in your attempt) will additionally sort the keys.

Comment: May I add one more little question. is there some way in jq to, next to replacing md with html to also prefix the string with _? f.e. `horse.md` gets `_horse.html`

Comment: @toni To unconditionally prepend each item with a fixed string, just use `+` to concatenate: `… | "_" + sub(…) | …` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Y6-4KTDOOgt)